PowerPoint userform format text with shadow using VBA
I have never used VBA in PowerPoint before. I have a sales recognition 'flyer'. Slide 1 are instructions. Slide 2 is the flyer. I created a userform that pops up so you can fill-in the flyer data. The challenge I'm having is to create the same text shadow effect you find on the PPT Home Tab (Font > Shadow) and mimmick this in the userform. One of the issues may be the numbers I used for Slides(2) and Shapes(14). The flyer is on Slide 2, so I think I have that right. I named the shape that contains the text the number '14'.
The following are three different codes I've tried, but no luck. I would greatly appreciate the help.
'Test 1
Sub setTextShadow()
Dim sh As Shape
Set sh = ActivePresentation.Slides(2).Shapes(14)
Dim tr As TextRange2
Set tr = sh.TextFrame2.TextRange
    With tr.Font.Shadow
        .OffsetX = 10
        .OffsetY = 10
        .Size = 1
        .Blur = 4
        .Transparency = 0.5
        .Visible = True
    End With
End Sub

'Test 2, same code as above, except I substituted TextRange2 with TextRange and TextFrame2 with TextFrame

'Test 3, I read online that this is all I needed to mimick the shadow 
Sub setTextShadow()
End Sub
Dim sh As Shape
Set sh = ActivePresentation.Slides(2).Shapes(14)
Dim tr As TextRange
Set tr = sh.TextFrame.TextRange
tr.Font.Shadow = True
    End With
End Sub

'Test 4
Sub MakeShadow5()
Dim sftShadow As ShadowFormat
Set sftShadow = ActivePresentation.Slides(2).Shapes(14).Shadow
End Sub```


It's not clear to me what's going on here, but if Shape 14 is, e.g. a text box, the first example subroutine works. Userforms are a different matter; they're VBA creatures, not PowerPoint shapes, so they have different methods and properties; a text label on a form, for example, has no shadow property.

Hi @SteveRindsberg I appreciate your response. So, I'm clear. You are saying Test1 should work without a userform? So, I retested, and it does not work on the slide. I found another code option (Test 4 above) and unfortunately, that doesn't work either.



You are saying Test1 should work without a userform? << Yes, so long as Shape 14 exists and is a text box (and NOT an ActiveX text box).   When it doesn't work for you, what happens? Nothing at all? Error message? If so, what's the exact text?  Smoke coming out of the back of the computer?  RUN!!


